# Change derive path

Tags: bitcoinj, android

I've used bitcoinj wallet and used derive path as below.

```
public static final ImmutableList<ChildNumber> ACCOUNT_ZERO_PATH = ImmutableList.of(ChildNumber.ZERO_HARDENED);
```

But I made changes in above path for generating bip44 standard addresses.

```
public static final ImmutableList<ChildNumber> BIP44_ACCOUNT_ZERO_PATH =ImmutableList.of(new ChildNumber(44, true), new ChildNumber(1, true), new ChildNumber(0, true));
```

Now As I load wallet in application then it loads from backup and app crashes because it took old derive path and I already changed it.

So it won't find old derive path and app crashes.

How can I change derive path?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

The bip44 derivation uses a mnemonic phrase and is standard if you are restoring it should not have problems. Are you mixing bip39 with bip44?